# How to clean unnecessary files from Linux

Tags: linux, files, delete

Each time I stop a zip process with Cntl+z a large temporary file is left on my server with a name like zi0RAB10 or zilsOZMP.  There may be files similar to this throughout the server - the remains of other stopped zip processes.  How do I most easily find/delete them?

Comment: Do you have anything in addition to just two file names to go on, like what directories, more filenames, what zip, etc?

Comment: It's possible to extract file names from an archive, but would you really want to blindly delete files that you don't know?  This is a bit tricky.  That said, I wonder how you could extract a zip and end up with files all over the place.  Where did you extract it?

Comment: @cutrightjm None of your questions have any bearing on the answer but since you asked:
/home/user1/public_html/,
zip2p6sV,
foo.zip.

One thing that may have bearing is that I used Cntl+z to stop the process.

Comment: They may not have bearing in most circumstances, but if you run `find / -xdev -name "zi??????"` without the `-ctime` part it would have also deleted  some man pages for `zic` and a couple of python files - if you had just updated something recently and it by some magical chance matched the regex `z??????` then you just might be SOL. Restricting a command to certain directories rather than just running it from `/` is a lot better in most circumstances

Comment: @JuliePelletier I am zipping, not unzipping.

Comment: Why do you pause the process with Crtl+z and then not restart it with `fg` or `bg`? If you really what to stop the process use Ctrl+c. Then the temp file will be removed.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens Yes, I just learned that that is what I should do in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find / -xdev -name "zi??????" -ctime -1
```

Comment: I didn't see the "zi" commonality at first, but @cutrightjm's question did spark that thought after I listed the third file.

Comment: I'd like to suggest passing the resulting list through `file` to confirm that they indicate 'Zip archive data', for extra caution, so you don't accidentally delete your zimbabwe or zillions files.